# Is IIS and TortoiseSVN working copy compatible?

Tags: iis, webforms, tortoisesvn, mapguide

I have a question about how IIS handle SVN folder.

I am working with ASP-Web forms and MapGuide. My problem is, when I set the path in IIS to my TortoiseSVN working copy, then MapGuide stops working. But when I just copy and paste all files from my working copy to a standard windows folder and set the path to it, then everything works fine.

So what does TortoiseSVN do?

Edit: here are some logs and errors

```
    2017-11-21 09:36:37 ::1 GET /mapguide/mapviewernet/ajaxviewer.aspx SESSION=78e11ef8-ce9f-11e7-8000-208df200a4f8_en_MTI3LjAuMC4x0AFC0AFB0AFA&WEBLAYOUT=Library://MyProject/Layouts/MyProject.WebLayout 81 - ::1 - - 500 19 5 0
2017-11-21 09:36:37 ::1 GET /xxx/xxx/MapContainerRechtsForm.aspx - 81 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:57.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/57.0 http://localhost:81/xxx/xxx/MapContainerForm.aspx 200 0 0 562
2017-11-21 09:36:37 ::1 GET /xxx/javascript/jquery.min.js - 81 - ::1%0 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:57.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/57.0 http://localhost:81/xxx/xxx/MapContainerRechtsForm.aspx 200 0 0 0
2017-11-21 09:36:37 ::1 GET /mapguide/mapviewernet/ajaxviewer.aspx SESSION=78e11ef8-ce9f-11e7-8000-208df200a4f8_en_MTI3LjAuMC4x0AFC0AFB0AFA&WEBLAYOUT=Library://MyProject/Layouts/MyProject.WebLayout 81 - ::1 - - 500 19 5 0
2017-11-21 09:36:37 ::1 GET /xxx/xxx/MapContainerRechtsForm.aspx - 81 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:57.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/57.0 http://localhost:81/xxx/xxx/xxx.aspx 200 0 0 31
2017-11-21 09:36:37 ::1 GET /xxx/javascript/jquery.min.js - 81 - ::1%0 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:57.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/57.0 http://localhost:81/xxx/xxx/xxx.aspx 200 0 0 0
2017-11-21 09:36:37 ::1 GET /xxx/xxx/MapContainerForm.aspx - 81 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+rv:57.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/57.0 - 200 0 0 515
2017-11-21 09:37:24 ::1 GET /mapguide/mapagent/mapagent.fcgi OPERATION=GETPROVIDERCAPABILITIES&VERSION=2.0.0&SESSION=8d781ed4-ce9a-11e7-8000-208df200a4f8_en_MTI3LjAuMC4x0AFC0AFB0AFA&FORMAT=text%2Fxml&CLIENTAGENT=MapGuide%20Maestro%20v6.0.0.8909&PROVIDER=OSGeo.SDF 81 - ::1 - - 500 19 5 0
2017-11-21 09:38:24 ::1 GET /mapguide/mapagent/mapagent.fcgi OPERATION=GETPROVIDERCAPABILITIES&VERSION=2.0.0&SESSION=8d781ed4-ce9a-11e7-8000-208df200a4f8_en_MTI3LjAuMC4x0AFC0AFB0AFA&FORMAT=text%2Fxml&CLIENTAGENT=MapGuide%20Maestro%20v6.0.0.8909&PROVIDER=OSGeo.SDF 81 - ::1 - - 500 19 5 0
2017-11-21 09:39:24 ::1 GET /mapguide/mapagent/mapagent.fcgi OPERATION=GETPROVIDERCAPABILITIES&VERSION=2.0.0&SESSION=8d781ed4-ce9a-11e7-8000-208df200a4f8_en_MTI3LjAuMC4x0AFC0AFB0AFA&FORMAT=text%2Fxml&CLIENTAGENT=MapGuide%20Maestro%20v6.0.0.8909&PROVIDER=OSGeo.SDF 81 - ::1 - - 500 19 5 0
2017-11-21 09:40:24 ::1 GET /mapguide/mapagent/mapagent.fcgi OPERATION=GETPROVIDERCAPABILITIES&VERSION=2.0.0&SESSION=8d781ed4-ce9a-11e7-8000-208df200a4f8_en_MTI3LjAuMC4x0AFC0AFB0AFA&FORMAT=text%2Fxml&CLIENTAGENT=MapGuide%20Maestro%20v6.0.0.8909&PROVIDER=OSGeo.SDF 81 - ::1 - - 500 19 5 0
```

How it looks:
[image]

How it should look:
[image]

```
Dim Response As Net.WebResponse = Nothing
                Dim WebReq As Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(URL)
                Response = WebReq.GetResponse <-- exception

> > StatusCode = InternalServerError {500}  ResponseUri =
> > {http://localhost:81/mapguide/mapviewernet/ajaxviewer.aspx?SESSION=48f61ece-cea8-11e7-8000-208df200a4f8_en_MTI3LjAuMC4x0AFC0AFB0AFA&WEBLAYOUT=Library://myProject/Layouts/myWebLayout.WebLayout}
```

Comment: Define "stops working". Any error messages? Event Log entries?

Comment: sorry, edit my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got the solution for my problem:

I have to add "Authenticated Users" group to my project folder. Because my web.config in that folder could not be accessed